# Distributing 20 audio files to 20 students, one file per student

Tags: email, google-drive-api, mp3, audacity

I'm a music teacher with a class of say, 20 students. Using Audacity, I've recorded all the students playing a short passage, and have exported each student's file as an mp3. How can I code a batch distribution of those files to students so each student gets their own file?

I can use Google Drive, email or other free options, and the files are all named for each student. There are add-on solutions [available](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPs7P_88_WAhXMzRoKHdgLCYoQFgheMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fmail-merge-with-attachmen%2Fnifmcbjailaccmombpjjpijjbfoicppp%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw0wYsptn5vH2_9PBsnLGftX), but I'd rather script it myself to minimize exposing student data; I'm just not sure where to begin with the code for that. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Send them an e-mail?  I'm not sure I understand the question...  It's going to be far faster for you to do this manually than build anything.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Brad, but the time it takes to attach these separate files manually once per week, over the course of semester or year, for each class I have, is not trivial. I'm still thinking it'll save time and effort having a coded solution. Is there no way to gscript adding an attachment of name n(x) where x = the number identifying the file at location z?